# Invert the results of Buckingham PI theorem.

Tags: physics, dimensional-analysis

Suppose I got one of the groups are $\frac{vt}{L}$,

$v=M^0L^1t^{-1}$, $t=M^0L^0t^1$, $L=M^0L^1t^0$.

Can I change $\frac{vt}{L}$ to $\frac{L}{vt}$, both them are dimensionless.

Comment: I got $\frac{vt}{L}$ as one of PI groups. I just curious, if it is right if I force $\frac{L}{vt}$ to be a group

Comment: Yes, you can. Note that the choice of dimensionless parameters is not unique. If you need, you can choose $\sqrt \frac L{vt}$ or $\frac{vt}L+2\frac L{vt}$, or any other dimensionless combination you can think of.